# Using std::move to send a std::unique_ptr to std::thread in VS1012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

The following gives me an error in visual studio 2012.

```
void do_something(std::unique_ptr<int> i);
std::unique_ptr<int> i(new int);
std::thread(do_something, std::move(i));
```

> Error  3   error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional   1152    1   scratch
>   It is helpfully(!) pointing at this definition in functional:
>   _VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_CLASS_BIND, , , , )

This is fine:

```
do_something(std::move(i));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am told that GCC 4.6 had a similar bug that was fixed in 4.7: "the std::thread needs to recognise when it's passed an rvalue and move (not copy) it into its internal storage and then should forward it on to the wrapped function as an rvalue again" Thanks to Jon Wakely <http://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

*Almost* nothing. In fact, your program is legal and its behavior is well defined.

The compiler error you are getting is necessarily a bug in the implementation of the Standard Library that ships with your compiler, perhaps connected with the fact that VC11 does not support variadic templates, and the macro-based machinery used to fake them is not perfect.

This said, even if your program did compile, you would still have to join your thread or detach from it before the `std::thread` RAII wrapper gets destroyed - an exception is thrown if the destructor of `std::thread` is invoked while the encapsulated thread is still running (unless it was detached).

Comment: @MattPhillips: That's a run-time error, and the problem is likely that `-pthread` was not used to enable thread support.

Comment: @MattPhillips editing my previous comment: you still need to join the thread in `main`, besides compiling with the `-pthread` flag on `gcc`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Correct, edited the answer. Thank you for mentioning

Comment: I am using visual studio, so the -pthread flag for linux won't help.

Comment: @doctorlove: That's right, mine was just a hint for Matt Phillips.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!  And you and @juanchopanza are right--adding the `-pthread` flag worked.  I usually develop with Qt and have never had this issue come up, I guess qmake does it for you.  And yes unfortunately this does not solve OP's problem.

Comment: @paulm: In that case you will have to upgrade your compiler (first make sure you are using a recent version of Boost).

Comment: Looks like shared_ptr is the only way to get it to build