# back_inserter for move-only type

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code the object 'queue' is non-copyable, but is movable due to a std::mutex.

```
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(thread_pool),
                std::thread::hardware_concurrency,
                [&](){return std::thread(handler(), exiting, queue);});
```

VC++2012 is failing to compile due to a private copy constructor on the mutex.  It is failing to generate the copy constructor for queue.  Why would anything be trying to copy queue?  It appears to me that everything is taking it by reference, thus no copies.

Comment: Side note: `std::mutex` isn't movable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*You* are trying to copy `queue` by passing it by value to the `std::thread` constructor. If you mean to pass a reference, use a wrapper: `std::ref(queue)`.

If you really want to move `queue` into the `std::thread`, you need to pass `std::move(queue)` to make it an rvalue. It still won't work though, [because of a bug in VS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712038/using-stdmove-to-send-a-stdunique-ptr-to-stdthread-in-vs1012).

Comment: How does the std::ref fix things?  the constructor for std::thread is template< class Function, class... Args > explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args ), which ought to collapse to taking it by reference, since the lambda captures it by reference, right?

Comment: @Graznarak The constructor is roughly specified as calling the first parameter with copies of the other parameters as arguments (30.3.1.2/4). Realistically, you have to somehow copy all of the arguments for the new thread since the local stack is going to be changing. So yes - the lambda captures by reference, the constructor accepts by reference - but then it makes a copy to pass to the newly spawned thread.

Comment: And this is why rationalising about code by examining a function declaration is not enough. One must _read the documentation_.