# Storing an std::thread object as a class member

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, c++11, stdthread

I'm trying to keep an `std::thread` object inside a class.

```
class GenericWindow
{
    public:
        void Create()
        {
            // ...
            MessageLoopThread = std::thread(&GenericWindow::MessageLoop, *this);
        }
    private:
        std::thread MessageLoopThread;
        void GenericWindow::Destroy()   // Called from the destructor
        {
            SendMessageW(m_hWnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
            UnregisterClassW(m_ClassName.c_str(), m_WindowClass.hInstance);
            MessageLoopThread.join();
        } 
        void GenericWindow::MessageLoop()
        {
            MSG Msg;
            while (GetMessageW(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
            {
                if (!IsDialogMessageW(m_hWnd, &Msg))
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
                    DispatchMessageW(&Msg);
                }
            }
        }
};      // LINE 66
```

Error given:

```
[Line 66] Error C2248: 'std::thread::thread' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::thread'
```

This error message doesn't help me, I'm not trying to access any private member of the `std::thread` class.

What is wrong in my code? How do I fix it?

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to copy a `GenericWindow` instance? `std::thread` can only be move-copied.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but Win32 windowing and multithreading usually do not get along very well. GUIs are singlethreaded, unless you have a very good reason to implement a multithreaded GUI and know what you're doing.

Answer (score 7):

On this line:

```
MessageLoopThread = std::thread(&GenericWindow::MessageLoop, *this);
```

You are passing `*this` by value to the `std::thread` constructor, which will try to make a copy to pass to the newly spawned thread. `*this` is of course noncopyable, since it has a `std::thread` member. If you want to pass a *reference*, you need to put it in a `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
MessageLoopThread = std::thread(&GenericWindow::MessageLoop,
                                std::ref(*this));
```

Comment: [I've decided I'm going to give this answer to one question every day from now on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18152978/923854).

Comment: When I change it like that it give a strange linker error: `C:\...\MySolutionDir\MyProjectDir\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WinMain referenced in function __tmainCRTStartup`. I changed it back the error returned back to the one I posted in OP. I put `std::ref` again and this error reappeared. I rebuilt the project, it didn't make any change.

Comment: @hkBattousai I believe that linker error is the result of not having a `main()` or `WinMain()` in your program - in any case it's unrelated to the question.