# Creating a thread as a class data member

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pthreads, qt-creator

I am trying to create a thread and keep the reference to it as a memeber of the class, and the thread calls a method of the class. Here is the code:

```
EventQueue::EventQueue() {

    this->dispatcherThread = std::thread(&EventQueue::dispatchEvent, std::ref(*this));
    this->dispatcherThread.join();

}
```

I am using QtCreator to do the build. And gets this error:

> /home/eventqueue.o:-1: In function `std::thread::thread<void
>   (EventQueue::*)(), std::reference_wrapper<EventQueue> >(void
>   (EventQueue::*&&)(), std::reference_wrapper<EventQueue>&&)':
>   /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:136: error: undefined reference to`
>   pthread_create' :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

What is the problem?

I was referencing to this post:
[Storing an std::thread object as a class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163284/storing-an-stdthread-object-as-a-class-member)

However I always get the compilation error described above

Comment: It seems you don't link with `pthread`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link against the pthread library.

With GCC, we do this with the `-pthread` option.

For example: `g++ -pthread ...`

Comment: Ah stupid me. Although I was using QTCreator, so the fix is to put these flags into the .pro file:  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -pthread 
LIBS += -pthread

Comment: We don't link directly anymore, but use the `-pthread` option for compiling and linking with GCC.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart If you'd pinged me, I would have removed my DV much earlier.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would have, if I knew how to type a pi character on my phone, lol.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart You don't need it, just type _@_, and my nick will pop up for selection.