# How does the standard threading library compare to Boost’s?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, c++11

I am re-writing a bit of legacy code in C++ 11 and wanted to make the processing more concurrent. I have read about C++11 threading library but wanted to see if anyone has used this and if you'd able to share you thoughts on how easy it is to implement?

Between Boost threading and this library, which one is more preferable and why?

Comment: C++11 thread is very easy to get started. However, I think it is not mature yet as it is somehow new and compilers might not fully optimize it yet. But for the future I guess it will be more than ok.

Comment: Which compiler? I had a few problems with VS2012.

Comment: I'll be using VS2012 with ATL COM.

Comment: @doctorlove: What kind of problems did you have? Thanks.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712038/using-stdmove-to-send-a-stdunique-ptr-to-stdthread-in-vs1012 - it's ok, bit some things just don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost threading library is the same than the standard one (if you activate the new interface) but it adds features which are currently proposed as extension for C++14/17. It also propose more synchronization tools than the current standard or even C++14 draft.

What you need to know is that the standard and boost libraries are actually low-level concurrent constructs, they don't provide yet higher-level constructs, but there is work by both the standard commitee and Boost developers to add such constructs.

I recommand reading the book "C++ concurrency in action" which describe in depths how the C++11 threading library work and what it don't provide too (like thread pools implementations).